# Find free tcp port using python3

Tags: python, linux

I'm looking for a free tcp port in linux system using python.
I use this code

```
from contextlib import closing

def find_free_port():
    with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as s:
        s.bind(('', 0))
        return s.getsockname()[1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(find_free_port())
```

Sometimes I receive this problem

```
  File "test_script.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(find_free_port())
  File "test_script.py", line 6, in find_free_port
    s.bind(('', 0))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Why?

Comment: when you want to close that after a successful run, you press `ctrl + Z`?

Comment: I'm going to guess that's caused by a normal race condition where some other process is doing the same thing, and probably getting there faster because of no Python overhead, our just luck. Put your function in a while True: loop, and let the exception pass.

Comment: I don't press ```ctrl-Z```, I think this is a race condition. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to kill the port that is already in use and reuse it again. To a kill a specific port in Linux use below command:

```
sudo fuser -k Port_Number/tcp
```

eg: In your case it would be as follow:

```
sudo fuser -k 98/tcp
```

But to answer your question, I think the below code will help you to find all free tcp port:

```
from contextlib import closing
import socket

for port in range(1, 8081):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        res = sock.connect_ex(('localhost', port))
        if res == 0:
            print (port)
```